# Change div on each click using vanilla js

Tags: javascript, button

I have 2 divs div1 and div2. My goal is to make them change on each button click

```
<div>
    <button onclick="changeText();" id="changeText" data-text="Enjoy!">Hello!</button>

    <div id="div1" style="display:block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ipsum leo,
        scelerisque at dapibus ac, consectetur vel ipsum.
    </div>

    <div id="div2" style="display:none">Cras suscipit ullamcorper elit vitae sodales. Sed euismod felis molestie lorem
        gravida a venenatis risus sollicitudin. Proin accumsan lorem in est adipiscing faucibus.
    </div>

</div>
```

My js-code that right now works but i can see that it is completely wrong written.

```
var button = document.getElementById("changeText");
button.addEventListener(
    "click",
    function () {
        if (document.getElementById("div1").style.display == "block") {
            document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("div2").style.display = "block";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("div2").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "block"

        }
    },
    false
);
```

What can I do to make this code look and work better?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I`m trying to change the text with each click. I click first time div1 changes to div2, second time - div2 to div1 and so on

Comment: Your code only changes the display; it doesn't do anything for the text.

Answer (score 0):

It will at least look a little better if you create variables of the two divs;

```
const div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
const div2 = document.getElementById("div2");
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can achieve this by toggling between `style.display: none` and `style.display: block` on your elements with each click of the button. For example, something like:

```js
function toggleDisplay(el) {
  el.style.display = el.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
}

const divEl1 = document.querySelector('#div1');
const divEl2 = document.querySelector('#div2');

document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (event.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
    toggleDisplay(divEl1);
    toggleDisplay(divEl2);
  }
});
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="changeText" data-text="Enjoy!">Hello!</button>

  <div id="div1" style="display:block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ipsum leo, scelerisque at dapibus ac, consectetur vel ipsum.
  </div>

  <div id="div2" style="display:none">Cras suscipit ullamcorper elit vitae sodales. Sed euismod felis molestie lorem gravida a venenatis risus sollicitudin. Proin accumsan lorem in est adipiscing faucibus.
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.text');
changeText.onclick = () => divs.forEach(div => div.classList.toggle('hidden'));
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="changeText" data-text="Enjoy!">Hello!</button>
  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ipsum leo, scelerisque at dapibus ac, consectetur vel ipsum.
  </div>
  <div class="text hidden">
    Cras suscipit ullamcorper elit vitae sodales. Sed euismod felis molestie lorem gravida a venenatis risus sollicitudin. Proin accumsan lorem in est adipiscing faucibus.
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively:

```js
div_2.style.display = "none";
changeText.onclick = () => {
  div_2.style.display == "none" ? (div_1.style.display = "none", div_2.style.display = "block") : (div_1.style.display = "block", div_2.style.display = "none")
};
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="changeText" data-text="Enjoy!">Hello!</button>
  <div id="div_1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ipsum leo, scelerisque at dapibus ac, consectetur vel ipsum.
  </div>
  <div id="div_2">
    Cras suscipit ullamcorper elit vitae sodales. Sed euismod felis molestie lorem gravida a venenatis risus sollicitudin. Proin accumsan lorem in est adipiscing faucibus.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a CSS class that hides content, and toggle that class:

```js
let divs = document.querySelectorAll(".text");
document.getElementById("changeText").addEventListener("click", () => {
    for (let div of divs) div.classList.toggle("hidden");
});
```

```css
.hidden { display: none }
```

```html
<div>
    <button id="changeText">Hello!</button>

    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ipsum leo,
        scelerisque at dapibus ac, consectetur vel ipsum.
    </div>

    <div class="text hidden">Cras suscipit ullamcorper elit vitae sodales. Sed euismod felis molestie lorem
        gravida a venenatis risus sollicitudin. Proin accumsan lorem in est adipiscing faucibus.
    </div>

</div>
```

Some comments on your code:

- It defines two click handlers: one with `addEventListener`, but another one with the HTML attribute `onclick`. The latter references a function you did not provide.
- `data-text="Enjoy!"` is not used
- `id="div1"`: don't create a sort of enumerated `id` attributes. This is almost always a wrong choice. Instead give such a group of elements a common CSS class, and then use a DOM method to get all of them in a node list.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend saving the elements in variables and using classes to hide the element using the classList.toggle () method.

CSS

```
.hidden{display:none;}
```

HTML

```
<div>
    <button onclick="changeText();" id="changeText" data-text="Enjoy!">Hello!</button>
    <div id="div1">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ipsum leo, scelerisque at dapibus ac, consectetur vel ipsum.
    </div>
    <div id="div2" class="hidden">
        Cras suscipit ullamcorper elit vitae sodales. Sed euismod felis molestie lorem gravida a venenatis risus sollicitudin. Proin accumsan lorem in est adipiscing faucibus.
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var button = document.getElementById("changeText");
var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
var div2 = document.getElementById("div2");
button.addEventListener("click",function () {
    div1.classList.toggle('hidden');
    div2.classList.toggle('hidden');
});
```